# Does a VM maintain its vmid when moved from one vSphere cluster to another?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmotion

When vMotioning a VM from one vSphere cluster to another (managed by the same vCenter, if it matters), does the vmid stay the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VMID (unlike the instanceUUID) typically changes when it changes hosts, since it is a dynamic ID that the host assigns when it registers with that host.  This is confirmed with an easy test, but see below for others that have done the same.

See here as well:
[VMID thread on VMware Forum](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/316818)

Comment: thanks - not what I was hoping for, but it's helpful :)